# how to create array table that include number and character

Tags: java, arrays, integer, char

actually i want the table have the header on the top like no.room, doctor name and the time
as for time i want it to show like 8-10 p.m
for no room like 01 and for doctor name like Dr.Ali. but i don't know how because as i know char can only has single digit.

```
  char[][] doctor = new char[5][3];
    
    
        doctor[0][0] = '1';
        doctor[0][1] = 'A';
        doctor[0][2] = '8';
        
        
        doctor[1][0] = '2';
        doctor[1][1] = 'S';
        doctor[1][2] = '1';
    
        doctor[2][0] = '3';
        doctor[2][1] = 'N';
        doctor[2][2] = '3';
        
        doctor[3][0] = '4';
        doctor[3][1] = 'R';
        doctor[3][2] = '1';
        
        doctor[4][0] = '4';
        doctor[4][1] = 'M';
        doctor[4][2] = '3';
    
    

  
    for (int i=0; i < 5 ; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j < 3 ; j++) {
               System.out.print( doctor[ i ][ j ] + " " );
    }

        System.out.println( "" );
}
    
    }
```

Comment: You can use a String instead.  However, I would recommend creating a class to  hold the information and then put each instance of that class in a list.   Arrays and most other data structures cannot easily (conveniently)  hold mixed types.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 0):

You can't store more that one char in `char` type. Instead of using `char` type, you can use `String` for storing multiple char. This is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for further reading.

Here is the code for using `string` for you.

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String [][] doctor = new String[5][3];
        
        doctor[0][0] = "Room 1:";
        doctor[0][1] = "Dr. Alex";
        doctor[0][2] = "8-10 AM";
        
        doctor[1][0] = "Room 2:";
        doctor[1][1] = "Dr. Mina";
        doctor[1][2] = "10-12 AM";
    
        doctor[2][0] = "Room 3:";
        doctor[2][1] = "Dr. Nadir";
        doctor[2][2] = "3-4 PM";
        
        doctor[3][0] = "Room 4:";
        doctor[3][1] = "Dr. Rahul";
        doctor[3][2] = "1-4 PM";
        
        doctor[4][0] = "Room 5:";
        doctor[4][1] = "Dr. Mahir";
        doctor[4][2] = "3-6 PM";
    
        for (int i=0; i < 5 ; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < 3 ; j++) {
                System.out.print( doctor[ i ][ j ] + " " );
            }
            System.out.println( "" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help and how can i put the header on top of it like room no and doctor name and time

Comment: I can't understand about displaying header. Can you please add an image or brief description? @adinalokman